# How to add node to monitor in munin using Python script?

Tags: python-2.7, munin

I am not getting the exact solution for adding node in munin.conf using python script. i tries using ConfigParser but since munin.conf is a sectionless file its not feasible to use that module. Can anyoune suggest me the possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a host or node in munin with python script can be done via using python's config parser module. Below is the solution for it :-

```
def addhost(self, host):
    cfile = '/etc/munin/munin.conf'
    hostname = host['host_name']
    address = host['address']
    # use_node_name = host['use_node_name']
    with open(cfile, "r+") as f:
        s = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write("[default]\n" + s)
        config.readfp(f)
        # config.add_section(hostname)
        # config.set(hostname, 'address '+ address )
        # config.set(hostname, 'use_node_name yes')

        #config.write(fout)
    with open(cfile,"w") as fout:
        print config.sections()
        #config.readfp(fout)
        config.add_section(hostname)
        config.set(hostname, 'address ' + address)
        config.set(hostname, 'use_node_name yes')
        config.write(fout)
    for line in fileinput.input(cfile, inplace=1):
        line = line.strip()
        if not '[default]' in line:
            print line
```

here, for using config parser we need to do some changes in munin.conf. firstly you need to write a default section into file at top,second write the data which you wish to write, third deletethat section. Inthis way you can add a node to monitor in munin via python.